# How can I use plugin views in my WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added two plugins to my WordPress theme:

1. WooCommerce
2. Lead Capture Pro

Lead Capture Pro is a lead generating plugin. Companies get registered and can view available leads and buy them. The login screen for the companies is through `WP-Admin login`. When WooCommerce is activated in the theme then I get redirected to `"My Account Page"` of WooCommerce. I stopped this redirection using the following code in `functions.php`.

```
function admin_bar(){

  if(is_user_logged_in()){
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
  }
}
add_action('init', 'admin_bar' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_disable_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

This redirects me to the company profile page where he/she can see the leads and purchase history.

Now what I need to do is to have a single page having both menus of WooCommerce and Lead Capture Pro plugin with the same layout. I am unable to call Lead Capture Pro view on my custom page. Need some pointers.

Comment: "Now what I need to do is to have a single page having both menu of WooCommerce and Lead Capture Pro plugin with the same layout. I am unable to call Lead Capture Pro view in my custom page."  -- I'm confused as to what you mean. What custom page are you trying to build?

Comment: @helgatheviking I think he is trying to access views of both plugins inside one page in some kind of menu on a custom page.

Comment: Right, but where that custom page should be alters the response. Writing your own custom page template, writing a shortcode, or writing custom code that adds a section to the WooCommerce my account page.... Need a lot of clarification before a good answer can be provided.

Comment: @helgatheviking actually i need to show all the leads in my own wordpress page. Currently leads show on dashboard panel and my other (woocommerce)orders show on woocommerce my account page. So i made a page called leads and add new tab endpoint name leads in woocommerce my account page. Now i just want to show the leads in that page instead of wordpress dashboard. Hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: I would recommend you update your question with that information, and also include the code you've written so far, and perhaps a screenshot. Better questions get better answers.